# Recursion. I don't understand proof.

Tags: generating-functions

Theorem

Let $a_0$ and $a_1$ be given and let $a_2,a_3,...$ be defined by the recurrence
relation $a_n=Aa_{n-1} + Ba_{n-2} (n>1)$
where $A$ and $B$ are constants. Then let $\alpha, \beta$ be the roots of the quadratic equation
$x^2 = Ax + B$

It then

if $\alpha \neq \beta $ 
there exist constants $c, d$ with
$a_n = c\alpha^n + d\beta^n$  for each $ n \ge 0 $

Proof:

It is easy to check that, whatever the value of the constants $c$ and $d$, the given formula satisfies $a_n = Aa_{n-1} + Ba_{n-2} = A(c\alpha^{n-1} + d\beta^{n-1} ) + B(c\alpha^{n-2} + d\beta^{n-2}) $

I can't understand why the above is true for any $c,d$

Comment: The statement isn't true for *any* $c,d$. It's true for those particular values of $c$ and $d$ that satisfy $a_n=c\alpha^n+d\beta^n$, whatever they may be.

Comment: Ok, I made a mistake. I meant 'particular'. But I still don't understand.

Comment: I also misread the question a little. This looks like exceptionally lazy proof writing on someone's part. The "proof" portion just says, "this is easy" and doesn't really explain anything. I understand your confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $\alpha^2=A\alpha+B$, we immediately get that $\alpha^n=A\alpha^{n-1}+B\alpha^{n-2}$ for all $n\ge 2$. Likewise, $\beta^n=A\beta^{n-1}+B\beta^{n-2}$. Since both equations are linear, it does not hurt if we multiply them by constant factors $c,d$ and then add, i.e., we have
$$(c\alpha^n+d\beta^n)=A( c\alpha^{n-1}+d\beta^{n-1})+B( c\alpha^{n-2}+d\beta^{n-2})$$
for all $n\ge 2$. While this holds for an arbitrary choice of $c,d$, we do need special values of $c,d$ to adjust to the initial conditions: 
$$a_0=c\alpha^0+d\beta^0=c+d,\qquad  a_1=c\alpha^1+d\beta^1=c\alpha+d\beta.$$
These are two equalities in two unknowns, and by the very fact that $\alpha\ne \beta$, this system has a unique solution. So with this particular choice of $c,d$, if we let $b_n=c\alpha^n+d\beta^n$, then we have $b_0=a_0$, $b_a=a_1$, and by the recursion equatlities $b_n=cb_{n-1}+db_{n-2}=ca_{n-1}+da_{n-2}=a_n$ follows by induction also for $n\ge 2$.

Comment: Since both equations are linear"
Yes, we can multiply them by constant factor.
But the fact, that it must be linear caught my eye. I mean: When we couldn't multiply?